# How to can I remove the nlargest element?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am triying to delete the nlargest examples of a dataset but I don't know how do it.

I get the data with the following code:

```
df_ae.nlargest(30, 'minimum_nights')
```

And I want to delete because this are the outliers in the dataset, I don't want to use the formula that drops the particular percentage.

How can do delete this data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach:

```py
df_ae.drop(index=df_ae.nlargest(30, 'mininimum_nights').index, inplace=True)
```

Note that it's probably good to add option `keep='all'` to your `nlargest`.